# onTouch on a view not triggered when touching its ScrollView child

Tags: android, scrollview, touch-event

I can't get onTouch event triggered on a container when clicking on its ScrollView child.

I'm using API 12 on a Galaxy tab 10.1.

Anybody can help?

Thanks

**Activity**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.dude);

        LinearLayout mylayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);        

        mylayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                // Only called when touched outside the ScrollView

                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* do stuff */
                } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    /* do stuff */
                }
                return true;
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Touch here trigger parent&apos;s onTouch"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                android:background="#b00000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Touch here DOES NOT trigger parent&apos;s onTouch"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
mylayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                // Only called when touched outside the ScrollView

                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    /* do stuff */
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    /* do stuff */
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

this should work... but you no longer have auto-scroll when you fling it hard... it'll be a sticky scroll moving only as much as you drag.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to create ONE OnClickListener and add it to all childs?
Maybe this could solve your
As the ScrollView makes it childs scrollable it wouldn't have an own area to click in.
(Correct me if I'm wrong ^^)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this code

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
onTouchEvent(ev);
return false;
}
```